# Custom theme template files

Tags: theme-development, pages, page-template

Im trying to create a Theme from scratch, its quite challenging, cause im new to WP. I follow [this](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/websites/how-to-build-a-wordpress-theme) developing process at Teamtreehouse. All is very good, its just, im puzzled with the template file creation.

Its all fine with `front-page.php` and `home.php` files, but eventually I want to have as well the: `partnership.php`, `gallery.php`, `contact_us.php`, `prices.php` files too.

Anyhow, when I created the `partnership.php` file and linked it to display the Partnership webpage title with testimonials and link to the webpage, I got default `index.php` to display. I understand that WP will display the `index.php` if it does not find any other file in the structure, but the files are all in the `example.com/wp-content/themes` directory. Im working on localhost.

It seems that WP did not recognize the custom template files.

Share your thoughts on this please.

Many Thanks

Comment: have you read the [Template Hierarchy codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)?

Comment: Yes Milo thanks, it is a bit confusing though. I thought I should ask the question here for that, that someone could explain the process in Capital letters :) sorry, as I mentioned im very new to this. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom page templates, yo have to:

1. Create file for your template.
2. On beginning of your file add comment defining that this file is custom template file (`/* Template Name: One column, no sidebar */`).
3. Manually set that chosen page should use this custom template.

Of course you can also create custom templates for taxonomies, categories, and so on.

Here you can find great image showing how exactly the template to display is chosen by WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thank you Krzysiek Dróżdż, I will have a look at your approach later tonight after work. Cheers

Comment: Hi Krzysiek Dróżdż, i did set up the page manually to use the that template, still nothing, will try to sort out. Thanks.